# nth-child where divs aren't directly children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to set the 2nd text block to have a different background colour however they're not directly children. Is this still possible without the use of jQuery?

```css
.wrapper .text-block:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
  <div class="heading">heading</div>
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
</div>
```

To make it clearer sorry, I would like the `text-block` divs to have a different background on the 2nd element. They are children of the `wrapper` div shown in the code snippet above.

Comment: What do you mean by "not directly children"?

Comment: Are they children of another element that you can predict the type of? Are they children of a div under the wrapper div or of a certain class of element?

Comment: `.wrapper.text-block` would hit to `class="wrapper text-block"`

Comment: Your example is not clear at all. .wrapper.text-block **is** the children of .wrapper.

Comment: And just so you know, pseudo-classes select elements, not classes of elements. By adding a class it acts like a filter and becomes more restrictive.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking. Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/7vabpp3u/

Comment: How predictable/set is this structure? Will the second `text-block` div always be the third child of `wrapper`?

Comment: @Santi no it won't

Comment: I'd say the answer is no, with the given HTML, and without CSS4, like `nth-match`, this can't be done without javascript.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like the text-block divs to have a different background on the 2nd element. They are children of the wrapper div shown in the code snippet above.

The most reliable way to achieve this would be to not use `<div>` elements for everything. Your `.heading` class implies that that `<div>` is a heading, so instead of a `<div>` you could use a `<header>` element instead:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
  <header>heading</header>
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
</div>
```

Now, to select your 2nd `.text-block` element, you need only use the `:nth-of-type` selector:

```css
.wrapper .text-block:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

```css
.wrapper .text-block:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
  <header>heading</header>
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The structure of the page isn't fixed so additional divs could be added into the class wrapper with other content elements e.g. gallery-block. I'm looking to always count all the divs with the class name "text-block" inside the "wrapper" div and on the 2nd one at whatever position that is e.g. 4th div change the background colour

Comment: @SamXronn then no, there isn't really a way you can do this without introducing some JavaScript or modifying whatever is generating your HTML to add a distinctive attribute to your second `.text-block` element. CSS doesn't have a version `.nth-...` which caters for anything other than *every* child or a specific type.

Comment: @SamXronn your case may have other workarounds though. Is that `.text-block` always found after a `.heading`, unlike the first one? If so, you can use `.heading + .text-block`. Will there only ever be two `.text-block` elements? If so, you could use `.text-block ~ .text-block` to select any `.text-block` after the first `.text-block`.

Comment: The order the divs are output is completely dynamic there could be 3 text boxes in a row followed by 2 gallery and a 4th text-box. Looks like jQuery is the solution in this case.

Answer (score 5):

For this specific case and just to target the second element you can use something like this:

```css
.wrapper .text-block ~ .text-block {
  background-color: red;
}
.wrapper .text-block ~ .text-block ~ .text-block {
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
  <div class="heading">heading</div>
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
</div>
```

---

**How it Works?**

1. Target and change all elements `text-block` after the first one

> .wrapper .text-block ~ .text-block

2. Reset the properties for the elements after the second `text-block`

> .wrapper .text-block ~ .text-block ~ .text-block

The problem with this solution is that you just don't target the second-element alone the way it works you will need to reset or change the properties back for the elements after the 2nd one.

Comment: Whilst this is a solution, it's worth advising some caution with this. This approach will mean that every single change made to OP's second `.text-block` and specifically that element's content will have to be reset.

Comment: Could you expand on the warning of content being reset please?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly yep I've omitted that on the answer but will add it as a note to keep it clear

Comment: @SamXronn so the first rule will apply to all text-block elements after the first and then second rule  changes all elements before second text-block so you need to reset all the values you change on the first rule trying to target the second one

Comment: @SamXronn imagine if your second `.text-block` had a lot of descendant elements of its own, and you wanted them all styled specifically because it's the 2nd one in the list: every change you make to *any* of those elements will need to be reset, otherwise every descendant of your other `.text-block` elements (other than the very first one) will also use that specific style. With this, for every style declaration you make here you'll also need to add extra CSS to undo it for the elements you're not wanting to match.

Comment: @SamXronn to expand further, that's because DaniP's first selector here matches all `.text-block` elements which aren't the very first one, not just the second one. Any style given in the first selector will be applied to every other `.text-block` and will need to be undone for those ones.

Answer (score -1):

If your code structure exactly like the code you posted I think its simply to use

```
.wrapper .text-block:not(:nth-child(1))
```

```css
.wrapper .text-block:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
  <div class="heading">heading</div>
  <div class="text-block">text-block</div>
</div>
```